# SQL combining COUNT with NO COUNT

Tags: sql

I have a practice question that I am struggling with.

Here are:

1. image of the table
2. my code and the answer i get
3. the answer im SUPPOSED to get

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: use fiddle or text, images are hard to read and follow

Comment: Try explicitly changing your JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN, because joins tend to skip over relations that are not found (in your case, horses that never had a win would not be joined in, and thus not show up in your results)

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you get the TeachersAnswers result from the query.

I think that you may use the below query instead of yours :

```
SELECT horse_name, COUNT(place)
from horse h
left join entry e on e.horse_id = h.horse_id
where e.place = 1
group by horse_name
```